# Java: extend JFrame meaning and 1 listener for multiple actions

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, actionlistener

I'm kind of confused. I'm at work right now (just started apprenticeship) and need to create a fully editable table (I'll use SQL soon). So I have 2 questions here:

1. What do you mean by "Don't extend JFrame"? Let's say I have a class called "TestDialog" and also a JFrame which is called "TestUI". Would it be okay to write

   `public class TestDialog extends TestUI` ?

   As I have understood it, one shouldn't create a class (called MyExample) and inside of this class just write

   `public class MyExample extends JFrame`

   Because you create a JFrame within an existing class instead of creating it seperate.
2. I'll keep it short - Can I use 2 actions in 1 listener (for 1 button)? Something like:

   ```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        Action_One; Action_Two;
    }
   ```

   - Or do I need to use 2 different listeners?

Okay that's it I guess. I'm sorry that I haven't written everything clearly, I just registered here and actually concentrate on translating things from my language into english. If anyone could tell me how to write here like in Eclipse I'd appreciate it, because I couldn't really find out how.

Comment: who says 'don't extend JFrame' ? nothing wrong with that

Comment: Well, I browsed quite a few questions here and I often read that people recommend it. That's why I'm asking. Someone wrote:"one should favor composition over inheritance"

Comment: yes, they are kind of right. But then you would have to extend from  a JPanel instead, and add that to the frame. I would say there is no real issue here. I have done Swing 10years and i extend from JFrame a lot.

Comment: Not sure about your other part. Have you tried looking at getSource() from the event object? That will tell you from which button the event came from

Comment: I don't know so many methods. Currently I'm using table.getSelectedRow(); and I also want to use table.getSelectedColumn();

Comment: @OliverWatkins Actually, there's plenty wrong. From a purely design perspective, you're not adding any functionality to base class, from a practical sense, you're locking you're self into a constrained container, as windows can't be added to other containers, restricting the reuseability of you component

Answer (score 5):

Composition over inheritance is an important programming approach. So I preffer following construction of GUI.

```
public class Application {

  private JFrame mainFrame;

  private MainPanel mainPanel;

  private void installFrame() {
    // initialize main frame
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Title");
  }

  private void installComponents() {
    // install all components
    mainPanel = new MainPanel();
  }

  private void layout() {
    // provide layouting
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel.getComponent());
  }

  private void show() {
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.installFrame();
        app.installComponents();
        app.layout();
        app.show();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Main panel has no inheritance from JPanel, but use an instance of it.

```
public class MainPanel {
  private JPanel mainPanel;

  public MainPanel() {
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); // or another layout
    initComponents();
    layout();
  }

  private void initComponents() {
    // init all components here
  }

  private void layout() {
    // layout panel here
  }

  public Component getComponent() {
    return mainPanel;
  }
}
```

The same pattern I use for each complex component (for example for trees, tables, lists, tabbed panes etc.). But this approach has one disadvantage: there is no GUI builder that support it.

About actions: you can provide a combined action. Something like this

```
public class CombinedAction extends AbstractAction {
  private Action[] delegates;
  public CombinedAction(String name, Icon icon, Action... someDelegates) {
    super(name, icon);
    delegates = someDelegates;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    for (Action delegate : delegates) {
      delegate.actionPerfromed(ae);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean 2 actions? You can do anything in the `actionPerformed()` method. If instead your question is "can I have 2 actionPerformed methods in the class" ie two actionListeners then it's a 'NO'. You must instead read on Inner Classes to do that.

And regarding your first question it's more of a design issue.
I would prefer

```
public class Example{
    JFrame frame;
    public void initialize()
    {
    frame.setSize(//params);
    frame......
    //other frame initilizing code

    }
    public static void main(string[] args)
    {
    Example example=new Example();
    example.initialize();


    }

}//class ends
```

while someone else may feel otherwise

Comment: Let me explain it this way:
I have an OK Button which has to do something. Now I want either click on the button or just press enter instead. 
mouseclick = 1 action & enter = 1 action

Comment: @Noxious          have 2 classes that implement the  mouseListener  and a keyListener ,   search the API for further info (i aint sure of the spelling),    write your action 1 code in mousePressed() method of first class and action 2 code in keyPressed() method of second class ,make these two as inner Classes , register your Button with Both these listeners ,Does that answer your Question?

Comment: I have no clue what API is/means and I have some problems to understand that "inner Classes" part. Anyway, I was just an idiot when I asked the question. I thought using any keys on the keyboard belongs to the actionlistener, but now that you mentioned the keylistener, everything makes sense. As I mentioned above, I just started programming and have no experience at all~ Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @Noxious  API ->Application Programming Interface , Java API lists all the classes present and their methods etc , also Reffered to as Java API Docs , has Useful Information [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ , and yes you are right in that pressing any key doesn't  count as a ActionEvent , it counts as a KeyEvent ,